# Is there a safe way to use an old kernel in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: kernel, 13.04

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. Everything works well, external for vga_switcheroo switchable graphics.

Doing some research  I have found that the problem is the way the kernel handles Lcd backlight. The problem is not present in pre 3.7 kernels.

I tried installing a 3.6-based kernel from mainline in my Ubuntu 13.04 setup. Initially it worked OK, but there were some issues with lightdm (it would take several "automatic" attempts to get to the login screen). And later my installation went corrupt (I only got a black screen after login, no matter what kernel I used). I had to reinstall.

Is there a safe way of using an old kernel (precise or quantal kernel, for example)  in Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: its always be safe that work best for you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a newer kernel? 
      [Mainline Kernels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

I tried 3.9 rc8 from there for a different issue and have not had any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been testing the mainline kernels regularly (up to 3.10 rc5) and they all have the same problem. It is very disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my backlight, adding `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'` to grub fixes it, needed for kernels > 3.6.11
Here is a command to do it:
`sudo sed -i "s/quiet splash/quiet splash acpi_osi='\!Windows 2012'/" /etc/default/grub;sudo update-grub`
Here is the undo command:
`sudo sed -i "s/ acpi_osi='\!Windows 2012'//" /etc/default/grub;sudo update-grub`
Currently running the 3.9 kernel

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it didn't work for me. The problem is when I switch to the dedicated GPU, I have not backlight then (the HDMI output works well). While using the integrated GPU I have no problem.

Comment: try `acpi_backlight=vendor` the same way i used the one above, may want to try both at the same time as well

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. The problem is probably in vga_switecheroo.